# Permission 'cloudfunctions.functions.setIamPolicy' denied on resource '' (or resource may not exist) error when building with cloudbuild.yaml

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

getting this error:

Step #1: ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.functions.add-iam-policy-binding) ResponseError: status=[403], code=[Ok], message=[**Permission 'cloudfunctions.functions.setIamPolicy' denied on resource 'projects/ewa-mewa/locations/europe-central2/functions/getBookedDatesV2' (or resource may not exist).**]

when pushing with following cloudbuild.yaml

```yaml
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args: [
      'functions', 
      'deploy', 
      'getBookedDatesV2',
      '--trigger-http', 
      '--runtime', 
      'python39',
      '--region',
      'europe-central2',
      '--entry-point', 
      'get_booked_dates']
    dir: '/workspace/get_booked_dates'
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: [
    'alpha',
    'functions',
    'add-iam-policy-binding',
    'getBookedDatesV2',
    '--member', 
    'allUsers',
    '--role', 
    'roles/cloudfunctions.invoker',
    '--region',
    'europe-central2',
    '--quiet',
  ]
  dir: '/workspace/get_booked_dates'

options:
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
```

what should be the right way to enable allUsers can execute the deployed google function via **cloudbuild.yaml**?

The first step passes fine and the function gets deployed to google function, but the second step fails, and it is not becoming allUsers executable, what is desired.

Comment: did you find a way to resolve this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

finally I fixed my **cloudbuild.yaml** to code like this - I used functions instead of alpha functions:

```yaml
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args:
  - 'functions'
  - 'deploy'
  - 'getBookedDatesV2'
  - '--source'
  - 'get_booked_dates'
  - '--entry-point'
  - 'get_booked_dates'
  - '--runtime'
  - 'python39'
  - '--trigger-http'
  - '--region'
  - 'europe-central2'
  env:
  - 'CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT=ewa-mewa'
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args:
  - 'functions'
  - 'add-iam-policy-binding'
  - 'getBookedDatesV2'
  - '--member' 
  - 'allUsers'
  - '--role' 
  - 'roles/cloudfunctions.invoker'
  - '--region'
  - 'europe-central2'
  - '--quiet'
  env:
  - 'CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT=ewa-mewa'
options:
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
```

but anyway I again stumbled on:

`Step #2: ERROR: (gcloud.functions.add-iam-policy-binding) ResponseError: status=[403], code=[Ok], message=[Permission 'cloudfunctions.functions.getIamPolicy' denied on resource 'projects/ewa-mewa/locations/europe-central2/functions/writeFileV2' (or resource may not exist).]`

but this led me here:

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#editor

and explained resolution:

> Assign the deployer either the Project Owner or the Cloud Functions Admin role, both of which contain the cloudfunctions.functions.setIamPolicy permission.

I set Cloud Functions admin for some_numeric_here@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com service account and it did the trick with next deploy.

The mentioned role can be set in your projects IAM & Admin / Permissions. Search there for your entity with `@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com`